# Use both meta query and tax query

Tags: meta-query, tax-query

I would like to use both the `meta_query` and the `tax_query`, but using the following I can get results for the `meta_query`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'     => 'whatson',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'meta_query'    => array(

                array(
                    'key'     => 'sc_related_venues_title',
                    'value'   => $location,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'  ,
                    'field'   => 'title',
                ),
            ),

             'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'eventtype',
                    'terms'     => $event_type,
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'         
                ),
           ),

            'posts_per_page' => '10',
            'paged' => $paged
        ) );
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `meta_query` is extremely slow, and scales very poorly as the number of posts and post meta increase. `tax_query` is significantly faster, and your related venues title shouldn't be a custom field, it should have been a custom taxonomy

Answer (score 4):

Would you believe it, as soon as I posted this I remembered I asked a question about a query last year. I had a look over it and I've adapted my new query like so:

```
$category_slug = filter_input(
    INPUT_GET,
    'eventtype',
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);

$cat_query = [];
if( $event_type ){
    $cat_query = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'eventtype',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $event_type

        ]
    ];
}

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => array('whatson'),
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'tax_query'  => $cat_query,
    'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => 'sc_related_venues_title',
            'value' => $location,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'  ,
            'field'     => 'title',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing `'compare'   => 'LIKE'` from `tax_query`.

`tax_query` doesn't have the param `compare` it's available for `meta_query`

```
'tax_query' => array(
   array(
      'taxonomy'  => 'eventtype',
      'terms'     => $event_type,
      'field'     => 'slug',
   )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using slug to compare your taxonomy.
Try with

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'whatson',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'eventtype'     => $event_type,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'sc_related_venues_title',
                'value'   => $location,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'  ,
                'field'   => 'title',
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'paged' => $paged
    ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

try belwo code for meta query and tax_query.

```
<?php
$category_object=get_queried_object();
$term_id = $category_object->term_id;
$name = $category_object->name;
$description = $category_object->description;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'whatson',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                            'key' => 'sc_related_venues_title',
                            'value' => $location,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            'field'   => 'title',
                    ),
                ),
    'tax_query'  => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'eventtype',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $term_id
            )
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged' => $paged
) );
?>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/279795/edit) using the [edit button above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/279795/edit) and add in a bit more explanation of what you did differently from the question to solve the issue? Code snippets with explanations tend to be more helpful to future readers. Thanks!